# Typescript error : is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>

Tags: typescript

I am really not able to see where my mistake is.

this is the mistake I get.
I understand I need to do some safe coding with some optional, but I don't where to fix it. Probabli the mapStateToProps:

I have tried :

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ articles }: RootState): IArticleProps => ({
  items: articles.items || undefined,
});
```

OR,

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ articles }: RootState): IArticleProps => ({
  items: articles.items || [],
});
```

[image]

[image]

**this is the code below** :

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}));

interface RootState {
  contracts: {
    accounts: string[];
    admin: Object;
    event: Object;
  };
  articles: {
    instance: Object;
    event: Object;
    isPending: boolean;
    items: IArticleOutput[];
  };
}

interface IArticleProps {
  items: IArticleOutput[];
}
interface IArticleActionProps {
  someAction: () => void;
}

type Props = IArticleProps & IArticleActionProps;

const ArticlesList = ({ items }: Props): void => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return(<List className={classes.root}>
    {items?.map(({ id, date, title, content }) => {
      <ListItem key={date} role={undefined} dense button onClick={() => null}>
        {title}
      </ListItem>;
    })}
  </List>);
};
const mapStateToProps = ({ articles }: RootState): IArticleProps => ({
  items: articles.items || undefined,
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: DispatchType): IArticleActionProps {
  return {
    someAction: () => {},
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ArticlesList) as any;
```

Comment: Your ArticlesList component is missing a return statement.  So it returns void and therefore can’t be used as a component.

Comment: Hello, I had an idea this could be it. I did add sthg like : const ArticlesList = ({ items }: Props): void. This not correct this way ?

Comment: removing the void does not help. actually

Comment: duh. silly mistake on my part. I forgot the return inside my component